# How to get Azure AD user's first and last login time inside Azure AD Application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Tried following but it gives summary on sign in activity doesn't give time or any specific user details

```
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getAzureADApplicationSignInSummary(period='D7') `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph API endpoint for audit logs is `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/directoryAudits` and the Microsoft Graph API endpoint for sign-ins is `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns`. For more details you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-beta).

You could use filter to get the specify people with specify application to get the first and last login time. And even though you login failed, it will also display the login record.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=appId eq 'xxxx' and userPrincipalName eq 'xxxx'
```

[image]

Comment: createdDateTime is  first login or last login?

Comment: On the top of response is the latest login and  on the button is the first login.

Comment: You mean bottom right not button? Also can you please share key for first login from the response?

Comment: Yes, bottom.Sorry for misspelling. What the key do you mean?

Comment: Like **createdDateTime** is giving info about users latest login and same way which bottom key gives info about first login .Hope this is clear.

Comment: It still be `createdDateTime`.Like this [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5HIr.png).

Comment: The response is just a json array, the property is same and just descending sort the login details.

Comment: Perfect @Joey Cai !

Comment: Is there any way to filter SSO type of events @JoeyCai

Answer (score 0):

You can use the audit logs api in graph and filter based on user there endpoint is something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditlogs/signins
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-auditlog-overview?view=graph-rest-beta